# Java array, using an elements of an array as a reference to get elements from another array, then create another new array

Tags: java, arrays

does anyone know how to use an array as a reference to get an element in another array by using for loop or another useful method?
For example, I got multiple arrays below, and after I run the program the output array will have

```
int[] array = { 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 };
int[] c = { 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 };
```

After I run program

```
output ={18,19,21,22,23,24,26}


//this is generate through below
output[0]=c[0];
output[1]=c[1];
output[2]=c[3];
output[3]=c[4];
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to know if you can achieve the output with a loop instead of hardcoding the indexes ?

Comment: You can access values like this `c[array[0]]`. Add a for loop to go through `array` and there you go.

Comment: yes, just wondering is there any other better way to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since array indexes are usual integer values, they don't need to be hardcoded:

```
int[] indeces = { 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 };
int[] values = { 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 };
int[] output = new int[indeces.length]

for (int i = 0; i<indeces.length; i++) {
    output[i] = values[indeces[i]];
}
```

(Code untested)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values like that:

```
output[i]=c[array[i]];
```

I'm leaving it to you to assemble the loop around the statement :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to achieve this

```
int[] array = { 0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8 };
 int[] c = { 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26 };
 int output [] = new  int[array.length];
 int cnt =0 ;
 for(int a : array){
     if(a < c.length && a >= 0){
      output[cnt++]=c[a];
      }
 }
```

this is a very simple solution there are of course other ways to achieve the same